# cross parachute - drag coefficient

Tags: spacecraft, parachute, drag

I would like to know whether there is a mathematical formula which gives the drag coefficient of a parachute. I suppose that the  drag coefficient is a constant depending only on the geometry of the parachute. I'm in particularly interested in cross parachutes.

I know that the drag coefficient (usually denoted by $C_d$) for cross parachutes is about $0.8$ but I could not find a specific formula describing $C_d$ in terms of the geometrical figures of the parachute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In general, calculating the drag coefficient of a parachute is an unsolved problem in fluid dynamics. The drag coefficient is also not a constant, it typically varies depending on the dynamic conditions (typically expressed as Mach number in the context of planetary entry, descent and landing systems).